# How to convert list's values to dict's values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list. Actually this is word's index.

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6]]
```

and I have a dictionary. Dictionary's value is word's vector(word2vec) and each vector has same dimension(of course).

```
dic={1:array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), 
     2:array([0.4, 0.5, 0.6]), 
     3:array([0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
     4:array([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]),
     5:array([1.3, 1.4, 1.5]),
     6:array([1.6, 1.7, 1.8])}
```

and I want convert list's values(word index) to dict's values(word vector) what a pair with dictionary(as you look below).

```
lst = [[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
       [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4, 1.5]],
       [[1.6, 1.7, 1.8]]]
```

Can you help me??

Comment: No, I cannot because your question is formulated poorly. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edit my Question. Look at me once, please!

Answer (score 0):

One can use the below helper function:

```
def word2vec(list_param, dict_param):
    for i in range(len(list_param)):
        for j in range(len(list_param[i])):
            list_param[i][j] = dict_param[list[i][j]]
```

The list will have the updated values as required. Would strongly recommend not to use reserved key words like list,dict... as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` because I love it :)

```
ll = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
dd = {1:array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), 
      2:array([0.4, 0.5, 0.6]), 
      3:array([0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
      4:array([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]),
      5:array([1.3, 1.4, 1.5]),
      6:array([1.6, 1.7, 1.8])}

res = []
for item in ll:
  res.append(list(map(lambda x: list(dd[x]), item)))
print(res)
```

Gives

```
[
 [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
 [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4, 1.5]],
 [[1.6, 1.7, 1.8]]
]
```